# How to write a function that returns a function in Python?

Tags: python, function

In one of the training parts of my course I was given the following question:

Write a function `make_multiplier(factor)` that returns a function which takes an argument x and which should return factor * x.

For example:

```
f=make_multiplier(10)
f(1)
10
f(2)
20
```

I have absolutely no idea where to start with this one; I have scrummaged through all my notes and cant find anything useful.

Could someone please give me a hint or point me in the right direction of what I need to do?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function that returns a function:

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        return 42

    return bar
```

You can call it like so:

```
foo()() # 42
# or
baz = foo()
baz() # 42
```

There's your hint.

Comment: aah perfect that gets it to work, I am a little confused though as to what python is actually doing when i do this, how does it understand the variable i put in at the stage "f(2)" has to be used in the indented function???

Comment: When you call `f()` you are calling the "indented function" - because you're calling the function that was returned.

Answer (score 3):

Dead simple, just nest your functions:

```
def make_multiplier(x):
    def multiplier(y):
        return x * y
    return multiplier
```

Nested functions automatically look up unknown variables (`x` in this case) from their surrounding scope, using the value of `x` as it was when the outer function was called. The thing to remember here is that functions are just objects too, you can store them in a variable just like you can with other python objects, and defer calling them.

This gives:

```
>>> def make_multiplier(x):
...     def multiplier(y):
...         return x * y
...     return multiplier
... 
>>> f = make_multiplier(10)
>>> f(1)
10
>>> f(2)
20
>>> g = make_multiplier(5)
>>> g(1)
5
>>> f(3)
30
```

Note how `g` was given a different value for `x`, which is independent from the value for `x` in `f`.

You could use a lambda as well; lambdas are just anonymous functions limited to one expression; that's enough here:

```
def make_multiplier(x):
    return lambda y: x * y
```

Another alternative technique is binding `x` to a keyword parameter, which means you could override it if you so wish:

```
def make_multiplier(x):
    def multiply(y, x=x):
         return x * y
    return multiply
```

or the lambda version:

```
def make_multiplier(x):
    return lambda y, x=x: x * y
```

and then pass in one or two arguments to the returned callable:

```
>>> f = make_multiplier(10)
>>> f(5)
50
>>> f(5, 3)
15
```

Comment: Hint != giving away the answer.

Comment: You can also use the `lambda` syntax to simplify this case.

Comment: @Will: `lambda` is just semantics, and then you have to explain the difference too. Nesting a function is simpler.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are right. It is just syntax. These simple cases are the ones where you can take advantage of it most though.

Comment: @Will: There, lambdas and a keyword argument version too.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Matt Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14012102/455276) or [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14012098/455276) closure methods (which is the right answer in this particular case) there are two other forms that you will see that are worth recognizing in Python.

The first is using a lambda anonymous function:

```
>>> f=lambda x: x*10
>>> f(1)
10
>>> f(2)
20
```

The second is writing a class:

```
class Multiplyby:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x

    def __call__(self,y):
        return self.x*y

fx10=Multiplyby(10)
fx5=Multiplyby(5)


for y in [1,2,3]:
    print y, fx10(y), fx5(y)
```

prints:

```
1 10 5
2 20 10
3 30 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lambdas:

```
>>> make_multiplier = lambda n: lambda x: x * n
>>> make_multiplier(10)(5)
50
```

10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.189 usec per loop

Using stdlib:

```
import functools
import operator

f = lambda n: functools.partial(operator.mul, n)
```

10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.148 usec per loop

Answer (score 0):

I'm not recommending this, I'm just showing what's possible in [point-<strike>less</strike>free style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming):

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> from operator import mul
>>> make_multiplier = partial(partial, mul)
>>> f = make_multiplier(10)
>>> f(1)
10
>>> f(2)
20
```