# How to write a function in python?

Tags: python

I am doing exploratory data analysis, while doing that i am using the same lines of code many times .So i came to know that why can't i wrote the function for that.But i am new to python i don't know how to define a function exactly.So please help me.....

textdata is my main dataframe and tonumber,smstext are my variables

```
# subsetting the textdata
mesbytonum = textdata[['tonumber', 'smstext']]
# calculating the no.of messages by tonumber
messbytonum_freq = mesbytonum.groupby('tonumber').agg(len)
# resetting the index
messbytonum_freq.reset_index(inplace=True)
# making them in a descending order
messbytonum_freq_result = messbytonum_freq.sort(['smstext'], ascending=[0])
#calcuating percentages
messbytonum_freq_result['percentage'] = messbytonum_freq_result['smstext']/sum(messbytonum_freq_result['smstext'])
# considering top10
top10tonum = messbytonum_freq_result.head(10)
# top10tonum
```

i have repeated the similar kind of code around 20 times so i want to write the function for the above code which makes my code smaller. So please help me how can i define.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Check this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012076/how-to-write-a-function-that-returns-a-function-in-python

Answer (score 4):

The function is defined like this:

```
def func(arg1, arg2, argN):
    # do something
    # you may need to return value(s) too
```

And called like this:

```
func(1,2,3) # you can use anything instead of 1,2 and 3
```

It will be

```
def MyFunc(textdata):
    mesbytonum = textdata[['tonumber', 'smstext']]
    messbytonum_freq = mesbytonum.groupby('tonumber').agg(len)
    messbytonum_freq.reset_index(inplace=True)
    messbytonum_freq_result = messbytonum_freq.sort(['smstext'], ascending=[0])
    messbytonum_freq_result['percentage'] = messbytonum_freq_result['smstext']/sum(messbytonum_freq_result['smstext'])
    top10tonum = messbytonum_freq_result.head(10)
    return   # what do you want to return?

# use this function
result=MyFunc(<argument here>)

# then you need to use result somehow
```

Your function can also return multiple values

```
return spam, egg
```

which you have to use like this

```
mySpam, myEgg=MyFunction(<argument>)
```

Comment: To be complete, you will get the result by calling result = MyFunc(<parameter>). result will then be set equal to whatever you put after *return* in the function.

Comment: you are using ((mesbytonum = textdata[['tonumber', 'smstext']])) command inside the function ,some times my variables are different,if i give the data directly it will always calculate for the operator.so please help me in that way.please edit your given answer if you can. Thank you very much .

Comment: @suri1617, just add some more arguments to this function and use them inside